# Прерывание закрытия окна при свойстве кнопки «ModalResult := mrOK»

Tags: delphi

Есть две формы.
В Form1, создается Form2, и потом Form2, закрывается кнопкой TBitBtn

*Модуль Unit1:*

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(self);
  Form2.ShowModal;
  if Form2.ModalResult = mrOK then
  begin
    showmessage('on Unit2 click "OK"');
  end;
  Form2.Free;
end;
```

*Модуль Unit2:*

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) > 10 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('"true", exit from procedure"');
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

При нажатии кнопки, необходимо не закрывать Form2, если условие в *unit2* истино.
Вопрос:
Почему при *ModalResult := **mrOK*** (компонента «TBitBtn») - Form2 – закрывается не реагируя на “exit”, и продолжается выполнение кода «*if Form2.ModalResult = mrOK then*» в Unit1.
И как мне при «ModalResult := mrOK», при выполнении условия, всетаки не закрывать?
Можно конечно обойтись флагами, но интересно всетаки таким способом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Процесс идет примерно так:

1. Форма получает событие клика (и определяет куда оно приходится - на кнопку).
2. Вызывает процедуру - обработчик клика кнопки (ваш код).
3. Если у кнопки есть `ModalResult`, то присваивает его себе.
4. Проверяет состояние своего `ModalResult` и если он не `mrNone`, то закрывается с ним.

То есть выходя из своего обработчика по `Exit;` вы никак не меняете внешнее течение кода.

Повлиять можно вызовом исключения (например `Abort;`), но это чревато другими неприятностями.

---

Делайте проще, убирайте `ModalResult = mrOK` с кнопки и ставьте результат в процедуре как вам угодно:

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) > 10 then
    ShowMessage('"true", exit from procedure"')
  else
    ModalResult := mrOk; 
end;
```

Comment: да, действительно обход - работает. просто и ясно. Спасибо

Comment: Ну просто все же хотелось узнать, в чем фишка игнорирования "*exit*", при "*ModalResult := mrOK*"?

Comment: @Konstantin78 обновил ответ

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за разъяснения... (P.S. а "Abort", я уже пробывал, еффект такой же, - ну да ладно это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: @Konstantin78 Тут надо смотреть код VCL, возможно,что `ModalResult` присваивается до вызова обработчика. Или там как-то ловятся исключения. Или еще варианты.

Answer (score -2):

В этом случае надо проверять условие не в событии нажатия на кнопку, а в событии закрытия окна - т.е. в событии OnClose (соотв. вернуть Action = caNone).

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) > 10 then
    Action := caNone;
end;
```

Ещё есть событие OnCloseQuery, но его я использовать не советую, т.к. там необходимо обрабатывать ситуацию завершения работы системы (см. [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745151/detect-if-windows-closing-or-application-tries-to-close-from-system-menu-wm-clo)).

Comment: По каким правилам? Не надо сюда примешивать дополнительные сущности.

Comment: Как чувствовал, что придерутся к слову. Перефразирую: "При нажатии кнопки, необходимо не закрывать Form2, если условие в unit2 истино." - для проверки условия при закрытии формы есть событие OnClose.

Comment: К словам никто не придирается. Если автор использует `ModalResult` то достаточно оперировать только им. Не нужно вмешивать сюда еще OnClose/OnCloseQuery и дополнительно усложнять логику.